# Modification of the silverlight PivotViewer Deserialization

Tags: silverlight, deserialization, pivotviewer

I was wondering if there is a way to modify the silverlight PivotViewer Deserialization to add a new type of data.

For example if I have a cxml like :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
     <Collection xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/collection/metadata/2009" xmlns:ui="http://schemas.microsoft.com/livelabs/pivot/collection/2009" SchemaVersion="1" Name="TEST" xml:lang="fr-FR">
        <FacetCategories>
           <FacetCategory Name="TEST" Type="NewType" /> 
        </FacetCategories>
        <Items ImgBase="SqlCandidates-370b2a7a413b4ec181a761fbcf6a709d.dzc">
           <Item Id="0" Img="#0" Name="AUGUSTE AUGUSTE" Href="/DetailedView/368">
              <Facets>
                  <Facet Name="TEST">
                     <DateTime Value="2011-07-01T10:08:57.273" /> 
                     <String Value="Test result" /> 
                  </Facet>
              <Facets>
           </Item>
        </Items>
   </Collection>
```

It would be nice if we can modify the deserialization method. In this case we can for example add the date followed by a text which will not be clickable for example.

So if someone find a way to do this it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

in the silverlight 4 version this is not possible, the display of the filters is connected to the filter panels, so will not be able to introduce this new type (even if you choose not to display it in the filter panel).

in the silverlight 5 RC version you can do a lot more, not sure if you can introduce a new type but you might by extending the base propertytype (PivotViewerProperty). this RC is released last week and i think your best chances are with this version.

Be Aware, the documentation on this new control in SL5 RC is still very limited.